# Push a branch to a remote on GitHub with the base branch set to a remote branch name

Tags: git, github, git-push, remote-branch

I have three branches on remote (master, development, featurebranch). What I wanted is that when I push **branch1**, it should try and push it to the **development** branch, or any kind of branches I prefer. I've seen examples of what I should do like this

```
git push origin local_name:remote_name
```

But when I tried it, Git automatically merges the local branch to the remote branch. I wanted it to have a pull request on that branch. There's this nifty function on GitHub where I can just switch and select the branch that I wanted it to be merged:

[image: branch selection on github]

But is there a way that when I push my branch to a remote branch, the base branch is set to the remote branch I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there a way that when I push my branch to a remote branch, the base branch is set to the remote branch I specified?

That means avoiding:

```
x--x--x (branch1)                         x--x--x
                          ==> push ==>           \
          y--y--y (origin/remote-name)   y--y--y--M
```

But rather get:

```
                                     y--y--y--x--x--x
```

That is only possible if, **before pushing, your `branch1` has been rebased on top of `origin/remote_name`**:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout branch1
git rebase origin/remote_name
git push branch1:remote_name
```

---

> Our scenario is like Master branch is the, let's say live app, every time we found a defect, we create a fix-branch (should be branched off the development branch), create our fixes and push the fix-branch to development branch first where testing and QA happens. Once finalized, push it back to master.

In your case, you need to rebase and push to a different branch, one which is *not* `dev`, because `dev` represents a different development effort, one of continuous modifications, as opposed as puctual fixes.

Create a **release branch** which represents the hot-fixes that you integrate one by one on top of `master` (prod).

Each time you see a bug:

- create a branch for that `bug`,
- fix the bug
- rebase the bug branch on top of the `release_branch`
- push the `bug` branch for QA to review
- once reviewed, push it to `master`

Comment: Is there really no alternative, maybe I just explained it wrong. Our scenario is like Master branch is the, let's say live app, every time we found a defect, we create a fix-branch (should be branched off the development branch), create our fixes and push the fix-branch to development branch first where testing and QA happens. Once finalized, push it back to master.

Comment: @Finks Ok, I have edited my answer to adapt it to your workflow.